# Capturar y retornar datos vía AJAX en PHP

Tags: php, ajax, poo

Muy buenas noches caballeros, estoy incursionando en el mundo de ***AJAX*** , y quiero entender la forma en la cual se reciben los datos en PHP, indagando un poco sobre el tema se que ***AJAX*** redirige al fichero que solicita y declara que tipo de datos se necesita enviar, ya sea por **GET** o por **POST** pero no comprendo aún como puedo capturar estos datos y mandarlos a un metodo de una clase en php que me haga una petición en la bd y retorne la respuesta a AJAX, o de que otra forma le puedo responder a ***AJAX*** para que aplique lo especifico al **DOM** de mi html.

```
introducir el código aquí
$(function(){
 console.log('Jquery is working');
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
      let search = $('#search').val()
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "task-search.php",
          data: {search},
          success: function (response) {
             let tasks =  JSON.parse(response);
          }
      });
 })
});
```

Tengo algo parecido a esto en mi *AJAX*, pero quisiera saber de que otra forma aparte del **echo** le respondo a *AJAX*.

```
introducir el código aquí
if(!empty($search)){
$query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE name LIKE '$search%'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result){
    die('Error de consulta');
}
$json = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $json[] = array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'id' => $row['id']
    );
}
 $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
 echo $jsonstring;
}
```

**Nota:** Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar Orientado a objetos en *PHP* pero lo que no estoy entendiendo es como hago para responderle a **AJAX** por medio de métodos de una clase en php, estoy algo perdido en este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Te anexo un ejemplo espero que te sirva de lo contrario no comprendo bien tu pregunta suerte

Ejemplo:

```js
    $('#btnExample').on('click', function () {        
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var description = "description";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "task-search.php",
            data: '{ id: "' + id +
                '", name: "' + name +
                '", description: "' + description + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alertModal(data.Resultado, 'success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alertModal(thrownError, 'danger');
            },
            complete: function (data) {
            }
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Caballero me si dieras un ejemplo mas especifico te agradecería mucho. yo se como requerir y como capturar los datos lo que no entiendo es como se le responde a AJAX y en que formato, leyendo se que es en formato JSON pero lo que no se es como mandarle la respuesta a AJAX.

Comment: Revisa [answer]. Esto en realidad no es una solución al problema planteado en la pregunta.